# ng-show/ng-hide and ng-switch elements showing at the same time

Tags: angularjs, angular-formly

Within an Angular Formly (angularjs) form - I have two spans that I want to switch on a model property condition. Whilst the search text disappears to show the spinner, it subsequently shows both momentarily before the spinner disappears.

I initially tried ng-hide and ng-show:

```
<span ng-hide="model.validatingRegistration">Search</span>
<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-show="model.validatingRegistration"></i>
```

I tried changing the markup to use ng-switch but even that is showing both at the same time when it transitions back to the original state.

```
<span ng-switch="model.validatingRegistration">
    <span class="animate-switch" ng-switch-when="false">Search</span> 
    <i class="animate-switch fa fa-spinner fa-spin" ng-switch-when="true"></i>
</span>
```

I tried using css to set a transition time of 0s but maybe I'm targetting it wrong in the css, or have used the wrong markup for this to work.

```
.animate-switch.ng-animate {
    transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

I also tried targetting with

```
[ng-switch-when] {
transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

Update - ng-if is producing the same transition issue where both show momentarily.
[image]

Comment: try to replace it with ng-if but adding a complete condition like ng-if="model.validatingRegistration === false"

Comment: @FarukT unfortunately with the transition both states are still showing at the same time momentarily.  So same result as my other two attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding:

.ng-leave {
    display:none !important;
}

to my css seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't want to make this global (not sure what else it might affect) so I made a utility class to apply to problematic ng-switch elements: `.flicker-fix .ng-leave {
 display: none !important;
}`